# вхождения массива значений в массив вариантов

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, linq, linq2sql

Допустим имеется два массива

1. массив это массив искомых возрастов [2,4,7]
2. массив это массив возможных возрастов [[0,3],[0,6],[0,11]]

Во втором массиве указанны минимальное и максимальное допустимые возраста.

Требуется определить все ли искомые возрасты занимают только 1 допустимый предел.

Конкретизация:
Отель размещение 3CH (0-3)(0-6)(0-11)
Можем ли мы заселить в него трех детей

1. пример 2, 4 и 7 лет. - да
2. пример 4, 6 и 7 лет. - нет

Comment: А если взять, скажем, [[0,4],[0,6],[0,11]], то разместить 2,4 и 7 можно, но ваше условие "*занимают **только 1** допустимый предел*" не выполнено. Ст*о*ит уточнить, что важнее - возможность, или единственность...

Comment: @Harry - Видимо я не так описал задачу. предпологается что 2, 4, 7 должны находится в разных пределах для удовлетворительного условия
т.е.
    0-4 займет 2, но при этом доступно для 2,4
    0-6 займет 4, но при этом доступно для 2,4
    0-11 займет 7, но при этом доступно для 2,4,7
Но для [2,7,7] - это размещение не подойдет
    0-4 может занять 2
    0-6 может занять 2
    0-11 займет 7, но при этом доступно для 2, 7, 7
т.е. в данном случае 7,7 занимают вдвоем 1 допустимый предел.

Comment: Берём минимальный элемент из массива 1. Из массива 2 выбираем подходящий элемент с минимальным концом. Удаляем элементы из массивов. Начинаем с начала.

Comment: @PetSerAi - Хм как вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Оформите ответ отдельно, уберите его из вопроса. И потом примите ответ.

Comment: @alexander-petrov Мне кажется это как вариант решения, а не решение., так как на больших массивах, это не быстроработающий механизм.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @PetSerAl получилось как то так, вариантов при которых данное является не рабочем найти не удалось, но на больших массивах это начинает тормозить и есть память, ищу оптимизацию решения описанного ниже

```
/// <summary>
/// Описание доступных размещений для детей
/// </summary>
public class SearchIn {
    /// <summary>
    /// Минимальное значение возраста
    /// </summary>
    public short AgeFrom { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Максимальное значение возраста
    /// </summary>
    public short AgeTo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка на возможность проживания
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="age">Проверяемый возраст</param>
    /// <returns>Может проживать</returns>
    public bool CanLive(int age) {
        return AgeFrom <= age && AgeTo >= age;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Проверка на возможность проживания в данном номере
/// </summary>
/// <param name="askAges">Запрашиваемые возраста для проживания</param>
/// <returns>Возможность проживания</returns>
public bool AccommodationCheck(int[] askAges) {
    // проверка на достаточную возможность размещения детей в номере.
    if (askAges.Length > search_in.Length)
        return false;
    // Перебор с наименьшего запрашиваемого возраста
    foreach (var askAge in askAges.OrderBy(x=>x)) {
        // Поиск возможного размещения с наименьшим максимальным значением возраста.
        var element = search_in.Where(x => x.CanLive(askAge)).OrderBy(x => x.AgeTo).FirstOrDefault();
        // В случае отсутствия возможного размещения
        if (element == null)
            return false;
        // Удаляем из массива вариант использованного размещения
        search_in = search_in.Where(x => x != element).ToArray();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается с помощью идеи олимпиадного программирования - scanline. Идея такая: храним отсорченный массив координат точек 2 типов : начало отрезка и конец отрезка. 
Наши отрезки будут массивом возможных возрастов. Пускай для начала отрезка point.type = 1, для конца отрезка point.type = -1. Заведем переменную balance, в которую будем записывать, сколько на данный момент есть начал отрезков(не закрытых, то есть мы находимся по середине отрезка), таким образом:

```
balance += point.type;
```

Когда наткнулись на точку из массива из искомых возрастов, проверяем

```
if (balance == 1)
```

Реализация довольно простая, думаю, сами справитесь(не знаю C#)